# View dockerised JupyterLab in iframe on same server as container

Tags: docker, iframe, ssh, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I need to embed jupyter-lab in an iframe on the same server that I have my jupyter-lab docker containers on. 
I'm trying my best to wrap my head around how to do it. 
I've created a docker image and I create a new container like so:

```
docker run -p 0:9999 --name container_name jupyter-labs .
```

Then I get the port that was assigned with

```
docker ps -a
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.
I'm trying to get it working doing something like this

```
ssh -L 8858:localhost:49160 root@x.x.x.x
```

and then setting the src of my iframe to:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8858/" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>
```

A lot of this I have learned in the past week or 2, ports, shh etc. So I am not sure that if this is even possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was an issue with ports being blocked my networks firewall.